# OpenGL ES as a 2D Platform

Tags: iphone, opengl, graphics

I've seen a lot of bandying about what's better, Quartz or OpenGL ES for 2D gaming.  Neverminding libraries like Cocos2D, I'm curious if anyone can point to resources that teach using OpenGL ES as a 2D platform.  I mean, are we really stating that learning 3D programming is worth a slight speed increase...or can it be learned from a 2D perspective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GL is likely to give you better performance, with less CPU usage, battery drain, and so on.  2D drawing with GL is just like 3D  drawing with GL, you just don't change the Z coordinate.

That being said, it's easier to write 2D drawing code with Quartz, so you  have to decide the trade-off.

Answer (score 3):

Cribbed from a similar answer I provided [here](http://iphonegamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12/compare-opengl-es-and-coregraphics-which-is-better-when/81#81):

You probably mean Core Animation when you say Quartz.  Quartz handles static 2-D drawing within views or layers.  On the iPhone, all Quartz drawing for display is done to a Core Animation layer, either directly or through a layer-backed view.  Each time this drawing is performed, the layer is sent to the GPU to be cached.  This re-caching is an expensive operation, so attempting to animate something by redrawing it each frame using Quartz results in terrible performance.

However, if you can split your graphics into sprites whose content doesn't change frequently, you can achieve very good performance using Core Animation.  Each one of those sprites would be hosted in a Core Animation CALayer or UIKit UIView, and then animated about the screen.  Because the layers are cached on the GPU, basically as textures, they can be moved around very smoothly.  I've been able to move 50 translucent layers simultaneously at 60 FPS (100 at 30 FPS) on the original iPhone (not 3G S).

You can even do some rudimentary 3-D layout and animation using Core Animation, as I show in [this sample application](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2008/10/22/3-d-rotation-without-trackball).  However, you are limited to working with flat, rectangular structures (the layers).

If you need to do true 3-D work, or want to squeeze the last bit of performance out of the device, you'll want to look at OpenGL ES.  However, OpenGL ES is nowhere near as easy to work with as Core Animation, so my recommendation has been to try Core Animation first and switch to OpenGL ES only if you can't do what you want.  I've used both in my applications, and I greatly prefer working with Core Animation.